# Resize fancy box based on image size

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox, width

I am loading some images into a fancybox windown. All the images are dynamically called and all have different widths and heights. I am having trouble resizing the fancy box window based on the image and its size. I dont want to set a definite width and height becuase the size changes.  I am doing this to set the size but I dont if this is correct. I've read some articles on the issue but cant find a solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [**fancybox api**](http://fancybox.net/api), it says it has this option:

```
autoScale: true //If true, FancyBox is scaled to fit in viewport
```

So you could pass that option into your `.fancybox` selector and take it for a spin:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoScale: true
});
```